# PyCharm: (venv) doesn't auto activate in terminal when powershell is used, but it works for cmd.exe

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pycharm

Windows 10 1909
Latest Python and PyCharm

In the settings when I set the terminal to cmd.exe it works, the PyCharm Terminal shows (venv)
However the virtual environment doesn't auto activate when setting the terminal to Powershell

Comment: when the PoSh terminal starts up ... is the needed path included in that session? the difference between various search paths is one fairly common reason for things to not work ...

Comment: How do I check that?  

In settings it's
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: Ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22469

Comment: @JimJamil - you need to check that while in the console window. you can use `$env:Path -split ';'` to get that list while in the PoSh window used by that account. ///// however, i see that there is comment showing a bug from 5 years ago in the VEnv stuff.